# Is it possible to render box-radius across a block when it spans a break inside a class?

Tags: css

```css
.mytext {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, red, blue);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  padding: 0em 1em;
  border-radius: 16px;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-left: 10px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<span class="mytext">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur
           adipisicing elit<br>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur
           adipisicing elit<br>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur
           adipisicing elit
</span>
```

In all three segments there should be a `border-radius` (both left and right side), without avoiding `<br>` tags in the HTML. Please help.

Comment: just add display block to `.mytext` if you want all them in the same container

Comment: adding block will destroy the segments.I want seperate borders to all three segments.

Comment: then why not separate the 3 segments in blocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `span`s around your inner text like this:

```css
.mytext {
  padding: 0em 1em;
  margin-left: 10px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.mytext span {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  padding: 0em 1em;
  border-radius: 16px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.mytext span:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, red, #ae0051);
}

.mytext span:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ae0051, #5300ac);
}

.mytext span:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #5300ac, blue);
}
```

```html
<div class="mytext">
  <span>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur
           adipisicing elit
  </span>
  <br/>
  <span>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur
           adipisicing elit
  </span>
  <br/>
  <span>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur
           adipisicing elit
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Split each section into its own `<span class="mytext">`:

```css
.mytext {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, red, blue);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  padding: 0em 1em;
  border-radius: 16px;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-left: 10px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<span class="mytext">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipisicing elit</span>
<br>
<span class="mytext">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipisicing elit</span>
<br>
<span class="mytext">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipisicing elit</span>
```

Or if you want to keep the color scheme going across all three blocks, you'll need a few different classes:

```css
.mytext {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  padding: 0em 1em;
  border-radius: 16px;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-left: 10px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.first {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, red, maroon);
}

.second {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, maroon, purple);
}

.third {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, purple, blue);
}
```

```html
<span class="mytext first">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipisicing elit</span>
<br>
<span class="mytext second">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipisicing elit</span>
<br>
<span class="mytext third">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipisicing elit</span>
```